# How to build UIExplorer on Windows?

Tags: android, windows, mobile, reactjs, react-native

I'm stuck on this:

```
D:/android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF W:\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/reactnative/JSCWebWorker.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jn                                                               i//react/.. -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/first-party/fb/.. -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/first-party/fb/include -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/first-party/jni/.. -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/folly -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/jsc -ID:/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include -ID:/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -ID:/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/backward -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/boost/boost_1_57_0 -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/glog/.. -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/glog/glog-0.3.3/src/ -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/double-conversion -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni//react -DANDROID -DLOG_TAG=\"ReactNative\" -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 -std=gnu++11 -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME=1 -std=gnu++11 -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -frtti -fexceptions     -ID:/android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  W:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni//react/JSCWebWorker.cpp -o W:\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/reactnative/JSCWebWorker.o
make.exe: Leaving directory `W:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/react/jni'
:ReactAndroid:buildReactNdkLib FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ReactAndroid:buildReactNdkLib'.
> Process 'command 'D:\android\ndk\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 22.729 secs
```

Any ideias?

I'm able to run

```
D:/android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF W:\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/reactnative/JSCWebWorker.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jn                                                               i//react/.. -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/first-party/fb/.. -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/first-party/fb/include -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/first-party/jni/.. -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/folly -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/jsc -ID:/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include -ID:/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -ID:/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/backward -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/boost/boost_1_57_0 -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/glog/.. -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/glog/glog-0.3.3/src/ -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/double-conversion -IW:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni//react -DANDROID -DLOG_TAG=\"ReactNative\" -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 -std=gnu++11 -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME=1 -std=gnu++11 -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -frtti -fexceptions     -ID:/android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  W:/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni//react/JSCWebWorker.cpp -o W:\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/reactnative/JSCWebWorker.o
```

And compile JSCWebWorker.cpp individually:

[image: IMG]

The error maybe is with something that should run after this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?